# Find intersection of multiple skip lists

Tags: information-retrieval

This is the algorithm for finding the intersection of two skip lists:

[image]
(*Finding Intersection of two skip lists - copyright to Stanford*)

We can see that the "jumping by skips" benefits a lot in terms of efficiency compared to moving one step at a time.

But here I'm curious, what if the case is extended to multiple skip lists, say 100 lists? Currently, I only think of divide and conquer, in which the multiple skip lists are grouped by 2, and sequentially derive its intersection and later merge the solution, which sounds time-consuming and inefficient.

What is the better way to determine the intersections of multiple skip lists with the least time spent?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a pointer to the beginning of each of your skip lists.

We will maintain two things:

- The current max value pointed to
- a min-heap of (value, pointer) pairs.

At each step:

- Check if all pointers have the same value by comparing the top of the min-heap with the max value.

  - If those two are are the same:

    - All current values must be the same (since min == max), so the value is in the intersection.
    - Add that value to the output.
    - Pop your min-heap, advance its pointer until it gets to a bigger value, and push the new value. Update max to the new value.
  - Else:

    - Pop your min-heap, advance its pointer towards the max value, skipping as needed.
    - If its new value exceeds the max value, update the max value.
    - Push the new value onto your min-heap.

Stop when any list runs out (you need to advance a pointer but can't.)

This is a slight twist on a classic programming interview problem "Merge k sorted lists" -- the algorithm here is very similar. I'd suggest looking at that if anything in this answer is unclear.